# How to detect when any app comes to foreground or lauched in android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, locking

I am developing a AppLock application where I have to provide screen lock when any new app is launched or comes to foreground.
For this I have to detect it. What is the best way to check when any app comes to foreground or launched.

1. Does android send any broadcast for these events, so that I can register a broadcast receiver?
2. Which android versions support it?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement LifecycleObserver in your application class

```
class Application : Application(), LifecycleObserver {

   override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.addObserver(this)
   }

   @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    fun onStop() {
            //your app goes in background
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    fun onStart() {
            //your app comes to foreground
    }

}
```

Comment: I question is on observing life cycle of all the apps installed on device.

Comment: As far as i know, you cannot do anything about that. But if you found any solution, I'll be grateful you share it with me.